# C++ Recursion Graph Coloring Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, graph-coloring

I am in an intro C++ class at uni, and we have a problem that I have been working on for a day or two, but I have been stuck and can't figure out why.  The lab is to solve the graph-coloring problem with recursion.  We input a file that has a matrix of vertices and their edges.  Example-

```
8
0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  
1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  
0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  
0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  
0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  
1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  
1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  
0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
```

With 8 being the number of vertices, and going in row-major order, 0 represents no edge an 1 represents an edge between the respective vertices.  Here is the rest of my code, without comments at the moment, sorry.  The code reads in a file, sets up a matrix, then uses a recursive algorithm to guess and check to see if the available colors(k) is enough to complete the graph coloring problem.

```
//  Alex Cherecwich
//  Lab7
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
class graph
{
    private:
        int n;
        int k;
        int ** G;
        int the_colors[];
        bool adj_vertex(int m, int c);
    public:
        graph(int x){k = x;}
        void read_graph(char * fname);
        void set_color();
        bool graph_color(int m);
} ;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
void graph::read_graph(char *fname)
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(fname);
    if(!ifs.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Can not open (read) file '" << fname <<"'"<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    ifs >> n;
    G = new(nothrow) int *[n];
    for(int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
        G[b]= new(nothrow) int [n];
        for(int j=0; j< n; j++)
        {
            ifs >> G[b][j];
        }
    }
    ifs.close();
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
void graph::set_color()
{
    the_colors[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        the_colors[i] = -1;
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
bool graph::adj_vertex(int m, int c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(G[m][i] == 1 && the_colors[i] == c)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
bool graph::graph_color(int m)
{
    if(m == n)
    {
        cout << "Solution Found" << endl;
        cout << "Vertex" << "       " << "Color" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << i << "      " << the_colors[i] << endl;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < k; c++)
        {
            if(adj_vertex(m, c))
            {
                the_colors[m] = c;
                bool r = graph_color(m + 1);
                if(r) return true;
                the_colors[m] = -1;
                //return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    graph B(k);
    B.read_graph(argv[2]);
    B.set_color();
    if(B.graph_color(0) == false)
    {
    cout << "No Solution Found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input should be a.out k(number of colors) and the name of the file to be read.  Everything works, and I get the right outputs I believe from what I have tested on paper, but I always get a Segmentation fault(core dumped) error message.  I am not sure why this is, perhaps I am trying to access some index that doesn't exist, I am not sure.  Also, whenever I use 3 as the number of colors(k) on the matrix above, I get this output, which is correct.

```
Solution Found
Vertex          Color
0               0
1               1
2               0
3               2
4               0
5               1
6               2
7               1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, whenever I have k>=4 on the same matrix above, I get this output, which still works but isn't the most efficient solution, which I we are supposed to output every time if a solution is possible.

```
Solution Found
Vertex          Color
0               0
1               1
2               0
3               0
4               2
5               1
6               3
7               1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also, the code works when there are not enough colors, but it still gives a Segmentation fault(core dumped) message.  Either way, any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also this is a page that visually represents the matrix I have above. http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/csc112/Labs/Lab7/g.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never allocate memory for `the_colors`.  It's pointing wherever, and you're lucky your program gets as far as it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
int the_colors[];
```

This is not legal C++. It is an extension provided by your compiler, and it doesn't provide arrays that magically adjust their size as needed. Don't use it.

C++ has `std::vector`, use it for all your array-related needs.

Comment: Another problem I can immediately see is `new(nothrow)`. Don't use this form (in fact you should almost never be using `new` directly).